# Fastest way to reshape variable values as columns

Tags: r, performance, reshape

I have a dataset with about 3 million rows and the following structure:

```
PatientID| Year | PrimaryConditionGroup
---------------------------------------
1        | Y1   | TRAUMA
1        | Y1   | PREGNANCY
2        | Y2   | SEIZURE
3        | Y1   | TRAUMA
```

Being fairly new to R, I have some trouble finding the right way to reshape the data into the structure outlined below:

```
PatientID| Year | TRAUMA | PREGNANCY | SEIZURE
----------------------------------------------
1        | Y1   | 1      | 1         | 0
2        | Y2   | 0      | 0         | 1
3        | Y1   | 1      | 0         | 1
```

My question is: What is the fastest/most elegant way to create a data.frame, where the values of PrimaryConditionGroup become columns, grouped by PatientID and Year (counting the number of occurences)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are probably more succinct ways of doing this, but for sheer speed, it's hard to beat a `data.table`-based solution:

```
df <- read.table(text="PatientID Year  PrimaryConditionGroup
1         Y1    TRAUMA
1         Y1    PREGNANCY
2         Y2    SEIZURE
3         Y1    TRAUMA", header=T)

library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df, key=c("PatientID", "Year"))

dt[ , list(TRAUMA =    sum(PrimaryConditionGroup=="TRAUMA"),
           PREGNANCY = sum(PrimaryConditionGroup=="PREGNANCY"),
           SEIZURE =   sum(PrimaryConditionGroup=="SEIZURE")),
   by = list(PatientID, Year)]

#      PatientID Year TRAUMA PREGNANCY SEIZURE
# [1,]         1   Y1      1         1       0
# [2,]         2   Y2      0         0       1
# [3,]         3   Y1      1         0       0
```

**EDIT:** `aggregate()` provides a 'base R' solution that might or might not be more idiomatic. (The sole complication is that aggregate returns a matrix, rather than a data.frame; the second line below fixes that up.)

```
out <- aggregate(PrimaryConditionGroup ~ PatientID + Year, data=df, FUN=table)
out <- cbind(out[1:2], data.frame(out[3][[1]]))
```

**2nd EDIT** Finally, a succinct solution using the `reshape` package gets you to the same place.

```
library(reshape)
mdf <- melt(df, id=c("PatientID", "Year"))
cast(PatientID + Year ~ value, data=j, fun.aggregate=length)
```

Comment: +1 `ddply` won't be much less typing, really, and it will of course be much slower.

Comment: Why would you even consider ddply for this problem?

Comment: Hi Josh, thank you, this works as expected and performs nicely. What would be the most concise/idiomatic way to reshape the data (if performance was not a concern)

Comment: Hi Matt -- I just pulled together an alternative solution, and added it to the post. Does that seem more concise/idiomatic?

Comment: Is there a way to do this in MS SQL table

Answer (score 1):

There are fast `melt` and `dcast` data.table specific methods implemented in C, in versions `>=1.9.0`. Here's a comparison with other excellent answers from @Josh's post on 3-million row data (just excluding base:::aggregate as it was taking quite sometime).

For more info on NEWS entry, go [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6913151/559784).

I'll assume you've 1000 patients and 5 years in total. You can adjust the variables `patients` and `year` accordingly.

```
require(data.table) ## >= 1.9.0
require(reshape2)

set.seed(1L)
patients = 1000L
year = 5L
n = 3e6L
condn = c("TRAUMA", "PREGNANCY", "SEIZURE")

# dummy data
DT <- data.table(PatientID = sample(patients, n, TRUE),
                 Year = sample(year, n, TRUE), 
                 PrimaryConditionGroup = sample(condn, n, TRUE))

DT_dcast <- function(DT) {
    dcast.data.table(DT, PatientID ~ Year, fun.aggregate=length)
}

reshape2_dcast <- function(DT) {
    reshape2:::dcast(DT, PatientID ~ Year, fun.aggregate=length)
}

DT_raw <- function(DT) {
    DT[ , list(TRAUMA = sum(PrimaryConditionGroup=="TRAUMA"),
            PREGNANCY = sum(PrimaryConditionGroup=="PREGNANCY"),
              SEIZURE = sum(PrimaryConditionGroup=="SEIZURE")),
    by = list(PatientID, Year)]
}

# system.time(.) timed 3 times
#         Method Time_rep1 Time_rep2 Time_rep3
#       dcast_DT     0.393     0.399     0.396
#    reshape2_DT     3.784     3.457     3.605
#         DT_raw     0.647     0.680     0.657
```

`dcast.data.table` is about 1.6x faster than normal aggregation using `data.table` and 8.8x faster than `reshape2:::dcast`.