# Nested if else statements over a number of columns

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, dataframe

I have a large `data.frame` where the first three columns contain information about a **marker**. The remaining columns are of numeric type for that marker in each individual. Each individual has three columns. The dataset looks as follows:

```
                      marker alleleA alleleB   X818 X818.1 X818.2   X345 X345.1 X345.2   X346 X346.1 X346.2
1   kgp5209280_chr3_21902067       T       A 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000
2 chr3_21902130_21902131_A_T       A       T 0.8626 0.1356 0.0018 0.7676 0.2170 0.0154 0.8626 0.1356 0.0018
3 chr3_21902134_21902135_T_C       T       C 0.6982 0.2854 0.0164 0.5617 0.3749 0.0634 0.6982 0.2854 0.0164
```

That is, for each marker (row), each individual has three values, one in each column.

I want to create a new `data.frame` which has all the same rows as in the original, but only one column per individual. In the one column for each individual I want the value out of the three for each individual which is greater than 0.8. If no value is greater than 0.8 then I want to print NA. For instance, in the data set I have given for the first row I would want the second value for 818 (1.0000), and the first value for 345 (1.0000). In the second row, I want the first value for 818 (0.8626), and for 345 none of the values are above 0.8 so I want NA to be printed and so on. The new data set would therefore look like this:

```
                     marker alleleA alleleB   X818 X345
1   kgp5209280_chr3_21902067       T       A 1.0000    1
2 chr3_21902130_21902131_A_T       A       T 0.8626   NA
```

I have been trying to use `if/else` statements, along the lines of `if [, 4] > 0.8 then [, 4], else...` however it doesn't seem to give me what I want, and I would also have to loop this command so it doesn't just do it for one individual in the first three columns but for all columns.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks - I should have added that in. All three columns for each individual add up to 1, so a value above 0.8 in more than one column per individual cannot occur.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Edit: Updated solution using the fast melt/dcast methods implemented in `data.table` versions >= 1.9.0. Go [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6913151/559784) for more info.

```
require(data.table)
require(reshape2)
dt <- as.data.table(df)

# melt data.table
dt.m <- melt(dt, id=c("marker", "alleleA", "alleleB"), 
                 variable.name="id", value.name="val")
dt.m[, id := gsub("\\.[0-9]+$", "", id)] # replace `.[0-9]` with nothing
# aggregation
dt.m <- dt.m[, list(alleleA = alleleA[1], 
         alleleB = alleleB[1], val = max(val)), 
        keyby=list(marker, id)][val <= 0.8, val := NA]
# casting back
dt.c <- dcast.data.table(dt.m, marker + alleleA + alleleB ~ id)
#                        marker alleleA alleleB X345   X346   X818
# 1: chr3_21902130_21902131_A_T       A       T   NA 0.8626 0.8626
# 2: chr3_21902134_21902135_T_C       T       C   NA     NA     NA
# 3:   kgp5209280_chr3_21902067       T       A    1 1.0000 1.0000
```

---

**Solution 1:** Probably not the best way, but this is what I could think of at the moment:

```
mm <- t(apply(df[-(1:3)], 1, function(x) tapply(x, gl(3,3), max)))
mode(mm) <- "numeric"
mm[mm < 0.8] <- NA 
# you can set the column names of mm here if necessary
out <- cbind(df[, 1:3], mm)

#                       marker alleleA alleleB      1  2      3
# 1   kgp5209280_chr3_21902067       T       A 1.0000  1 1.0000
# 2 chr3_21902130_21902131_A_T       A       T 0.8626 NA 0.8626
# 3 chr3_21902134_21902135_T_C       T       C     NA NA     NA
```

`gl(3,3)` gives a factor with values `1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3` with levels `1,2,3`. That is, `tapply` will take the values `x` 3 at a time and get their `max` (first 3, next 3 and the last 3). And `apply` sends each row one by one.

---

**Solution 2:** A `data.table` solution with `melt` and `cast` within `data.table` **without** using `reshape` or `reshape2`:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
# melt your data.table to long format
dt.melt <- dt[, list(id = names(.SD), val = unlist(.SD)), 
                  by=list(marker, alleleA, alleleB)]
# replace `.[0-9]` with nothing
dt.melt[, id := gsub("\\.[0-9]+$", "", id)]
# get max value grouping by marker and id
dt.melt <- dt.melt[, list(alleleA = alleleA[1], 
                      alleleB = alleleB[1], 
                      val = max(val)), 
        keyby=list(marker, id)][val <= 0.8, val := NA]
# edit mnel (use setattr(,'names') to avoid copy by `names<-` within `setNames`
dt.cast <- dt.melt[, as.list(setattr(val,'names', id)), 
                   by=list(marker, alleleA, alleleB)]

#                        marker alleleA alleleB X345   X346   X818
# 1: chr3_21902130_21902131_A_T       A       T   NA 0.8626 0.8626
# 2: chr3_21902134_21902135_T_C       T       C   NA     NA     NA
# 3:   kgp5209280_chr3_21902067       T       A    1 1.0000 1.0000
```

Comment: I found a post on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902087/proper-fastest-way-to-reshape-a-data-table/15512437#15512437) that was wondering how to reshape with `data.table`. No one came up with your solution there, so I just adjusted your example and posted it as a solution...your code is fast, man! Let's see if Matthew checks this or the other thread...maybe this could make it into the package as a function?

Comment: @Christoph_J Good idea: duly filed as [FR#2627](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2627&group_id=240&atid=978)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. I chose Aruns answer because the first answer he gave was simple and I could adapt it to a much larger dataset simply by changing the levels in the gl factor. As my actual dataset has more than 3 individuals, this was incredibly useful.

Comment: It would be very interesting to see Solution 2 written using similar syntax as `melt()`, i.e. with `id.vars` and `measure.vars`. This would be very helpful to allow users to move from a data.frame-based work flow to a data.table-based work flow.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is better here to put your data  in the long format. Here a solution based on `reshape2` package , maybe similar to second @Arun solution but syntactically different

```
library(reshape2)
dat.m <- melt(dat,id.vars=1:3)
dat.m$variable <- gsub('[.].*','',dat.m$variable)
dcast(dat.m,...~variable,fun.aggregate=function(x){
   res <- NA_real_
   if(length(x) > 0 && max(x)> 0.8)
      res <- max(x)
   res
})

                      marker alleleA alleleB X345   X346   X818
1 chr3_21902130_21902131_A_T       A       T   NA 0.8626 0.8626
2 chr3_21902134_21902135_T_C       T       C   NA     NA     NA
3   kgp5209280_chr3_21902067       T       A    1 1.0000 1.0000
```

Comment: +1 Nice solution. There is just one typo (it's reshape2, not rehsape2).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach using the function `pmax`. Note that this will give you the maximum if there are two or more values above 0.8 for each individual:

```
df <- read.table(textConnection("                      marker alleleA alleleB   X818 X818.1 X818.2   X345 X345.1 X345.2   X346 X346.1 X346.2
1   kgp5209280_chr3_21902067       T       A 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000
2 chr3_21902130_21902131_A_T       A       T 0.8626 0.1356 0.0018 0.7676 0.2170 0.0154 0.8626 0.1356 0.0018
3 chr3_21902134_21902135_T_C       T       C 0.6982 0.2854 0.0164 0.5617 0.3749 0.0634 0.6982 0.2854 0.0164"), header=TRUE)

#data.table solution
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
DT[, M818 := ifelse(pmax(X818, X818.1, X818.2) > 0.8, pmax(X818, X818.1, X818.2), NA)]
DT[, M345 := ifelse(pmax(X345, X345.1, X345.2) > 0.8, pmax(X345, X345.1, X345.2), NA)]
DT[, M346 := ifelse(pmax(X346, X346.1, X346.2) > 0.8, pmax(X346, X346.1, X346.2), NA)]

#Base R solution
df$M818 <- ifelse(pmax(df$X818, df$X818.1, df$X818.2) > 0.8, pmax(df$X818, df$X818.1, df$X818.2), NA)
df$M345 <- ifelse(pmax(df$X345, df$X345.1, df$X345.2) > 0.8, pmax(df$X345, df$X345.1, df$X345.2), NA)
df$M346 <- ifelse(pmax(df$X346, df$X346.1, df$X346.2) > 0.8, pmax(df$X346, df$X346.1, df$X346.2), NA)
```

If you want to get rid of the other columns, just type:

```
DT[, list(marker, alleleA, alleleB, M818, M345, M346)]
                       marker alleleA alleleB   M818 M345   M346
1:   kgp5209280_chr3_21902067       T       A 1.0000    1 1.0000
2: chr3_21902130_21902131_A_T       A       T 0.8626   NA 0.8626
3: chr3_21902134_21902135_T_C       T       C     NA   NA     NA
```

Answer (score 0):

These is an other possible solution. All solution above are valid.

My solution is create a function for your case-sensitive without the use of a new library. It's quite long and it's possible to compact, but it's useful to see each step in order to understand how the function works.

```
olddf <- data.frame(marker = c("kgp5209280_chr3_21902067",
        "chr3_21902130_21902131_A_T",
        "chr3_21902134_21902135_T_C"),
        alleleA = c("T","A","T"),
        alleleB = c("A","T","C"),
        X818 = c(0.0000,0.8626,0.6982),
        X818.1 = c(1.0000,0.1356,0.2854),
        X818.2 = c(0.0000,0.0018,0.0164),
        X345 = c(1.0000,0.7676, 0.5617),
        X345.1 = c(0.0000, 0.2170, 0.3749),
        X345.2 = c(0.0000, 0.0154, 0.0634),   
        X346 = c(0.0000, 0.8626, 0.6982),
        X346.1 = c(1.0000,0.1356, 0.2854), 
        X346.2 = c(0.0000, 0.0018, 0.0164))


mergeallele <- function(arguments,threshold = 0.8){
    n <- nrow(arguments)
    # Creation of a results object as an empty list of length NROW
    # speed for huge data.frame 
    new.lst <- vector(mode="list", n)
    for (i in 1:n){
        marker_row <- arguments[i,]
        colvalue.4 <- NaN
        if (max(marker_row[,c(4:6)]) < threshold){
            colvalue.4 <- max(marker_row[,c(4:6)])
        }

        colvalue.5 <- NaN       
        if (max(marker_row[,c(7:9)]) < threshold){
            colvalue.5 <- max(marker_row[,c(7:9)])
        }

        colvalue.6 <- NaN       
        if (max(marker_row[,c(10:12)]) < threshold){
            colvalue.6 <- max(marker_row[,c(10:12)])
        }
        new.lst[[i]]  <- data.frame(marker_row[,1],
            marker_row[,2],
            marker_row[,3],
            colvalue.4,
            colvalue.5,
            colvalue.6)     
    }   
    new.df <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind",new.lst))
    names(new.df) <-  c(colnames(arguments)[1],
                    colnames(arguments)[2],
                    colnames(arguments)[3],
                    colnames(arguments)[4],
                    colnames(arguments)[7],
                    colnames(arguments)[10])
    return(new.df)
}


newdf <- mergeallele(olddf)

                      marker alleleA alleleB   X818   X345   X346
1   kgp5209280_chr3_21902067       T       A    NaN    NaN    NaN
2 chr3_21902130_21902131_A_T       A       T    NaN 0.7676    NaN
3 chr3_21902134_21902135_T_C       T       C 0.6982 0.5617 0.6982
```

about:

```
threshold = 0.8
```

you can set your the threshold value (ex: 0.8) avoid to change variable inside the function

```
new.lst <- vector(mode="list", n)
```

you can create a empty list of length the old data.frame and the elements of the list are then gradually filled with the loop results (much faster). See the test speed from this [Blog](http://menugget.blogspot.dk/2011/11/another-aspect-of-speeding-up-loops-in.html)