# Group by while calculating multiple values

Tags: r, group-by, data.table

I'm trying to use a function that calculates some statistics by group in a `data.table` as follows:

```
minmax <- function(vec) {
  c(min(vec), max(vec))
}
library(data.table)
iris <- as.data.table(iris)
iris[, c('Min', 'Max') := minmax(Petal.Length), by = Species]
```

The result should be the min and max `Petal.Length` by `Species` and have as many rows as there are Species. That is, the same result as the code below:

```
merge(
  iris[, .(Min = min(Petal.Length)), Species],
  iris[, .(Max = max(Petal.Length)), Species],
  on = 'Species'
)

      Species Min Max
1:     setosa 1.0 1.9
2: versicolor 3.0 5.1
3:  virginica 4.5 6.9
```

Note: in my own code I want to do this in one go, not using `merge()`.

Comment: Related: [Create aggregate output data.table from function returning multiple output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425121/create-aggregate-output-data-table-from-function-returning-multiple-output)

Comment: Thank you @Henrik, I struggled momentarily to find the dupe (and then gave up looking).

Comment: I don't mind closing this question as a dupe but I think your answer definitely has merit compared to the original one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things here:

1. The `:=` is for adding columns to an existing frame, so it will not summarize as you've demonstrated. That is, `DT[, a := b]` should always have exactly the same number of rows. I think this is not what you need.
2. You can do multiple-assignment in your summarizing code and do away with the `merge` (perhaps this is similar to the code you said you do "in one go"):

   ```r
   iris[, .(Min = min(Petal.Length), Max = max(Petal.Length)), by = .(Species)]
   #       Species   Min   Max
   #        <fctr> <num> <num>
   # 1:     setosa   1.0   1.9
   # 2: versicolor   3.0   5.1
   # 3:  virginica   4.5   6.9
   ```
3. But finally, you are asking how to use your function to get this. First attempts might be:

   ```r
   minmax <- function(vec) c(min(vec), max(vec))
   iris[, minmax(Petal.Length), by = .(Species)]
   #       Species    V1
   #        <fctr> <num>
   # 1:     setosa   1.0
   # 2:     setosa   1.9
   # 3: versicolor   3.0
   # 4: versicolor   5.1
   # 5:  virginica   4.5
   # 6:  virginica   6.9

   iris[, as.list(minmax(Petal.Length)), by = .(Species)]
   #       Species    V1    V2
   #        <fctr> <num> <num>
   # 1:     setosa   1.0   1.9
   # 2: versicolor   3.0   5.1
   # 3:  virginica   4.5   6.9

   iris[, setNames(as.list(minmax(Petal.Length)), c("Min", "Max")), by = .(Species)]
   #       Species   Min   Max
   #        <fctr> <num> <num>
   # 1:     setosa   1.0   1.9
   # 2: versicolor   3.0   5.1
   # 3:  virginica   4.5   6.9

   minmax <- function(vec) c(Min = min(vec), Max = max(vec))
   iris[, as.list(minmax(Petal.Length)), by = .(Species)]
   #       Species   Min   Max
   #        <fctr> <num> <num>
   # 1:     setosa   1.0   1.9
   # 2: versicolor   3.0   5.1
   # 3:  virginica   4.5   6.9
   ```

   So we can change the function to return a list (optionally named).

   ```r
   minmax <- function(vec) list(min(vec), max(vec))
   iris[, minmax(Petal.Length), by = .(Species)]
   #       Species    V1    V2
   #        <fctr> <num> <num>
   # 1:     setosa   1.0   1.9
   # 2: versicolor   3.0   5.1
   # 3:  virginica   4.5   6.9
   iris[, setNames(minmax(Petal.Length), c("Min", "Max")), by = .(Species)]
   #       Species   Min   Max
   #        <fctr> <num> <num>
   # 1:     setosa   1.0   1.9
   # 2: versicolor   3.0   5.1
   # 3:  virginica   4.5   6.9

   minmax <- function(vec) list(Min = min(vec), Max = max(vec))
   iris[, minmax(Petal.Length), by = .(Species)]
   #       Species   Min   Max
   #        <fctr> <num> <num>
   # 1:     setosa   1.0   1.9
   # 2: versicolor   3.0   5.1
   # 3:  virginica   4.5   6.9
   ```

Comment: This will work for me, thanks! It's not possible to specify the column names inside the `[`?

Comment: There are several options in this answer that allow you to set names on the return value given the function does not name them itself. See the use of `setNames(as.list(...))`, recently edited in.

Comment: The key for both *summarizing* and *naming* is to produce a `list` (`as.list`) and use `setNames` without actual `:=`-assignment.

Comment: Yes, now I see. I was stuck on trying to use  a vector. Using a vector was not a great idea in any case because it can't handle multiple types.

Comment: @BobJansen Just remember the basic property of `j`; straight from the help text: "As long as `j` returns a `list`, each element of the list becomes a column in the resulting `data.table`" Cheers