# R data.table reshape chunks of columns at once

Tags: r, data.table, reshape

Lets say I have a `data.table` with these columns

```
nodeID   
hour1aaa   
hour1bbb   
hour1ccc   
hour2aaa   
hour2bbb   
hour2ccc   
...   
hour24aaa   
hour24bbb   
hour24ccc
```

for a total of 72 columns.  Let's call it `rawtable`

I want to reshape it so I have

```
nodeID
hour
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

for a total of just these 5 columns
where the hour column will contain whichever hour from the original 72 that it should be.
Let's call it `newshape`

The way I'm doing it now is to use `rbindlist` with 24 items where each item is the proper subset of the bigger data.table.  Like this (except I'm leaving out most of the hours in my example)

```
newshape<-rbindlist(list(
 rawtable[,list(nodeID, Hour=1, aaa=hour1aaa, bbb=hour1bbb, ccc=hour1ccc)], 
 rawtable[,list(nodeID, Hour=2, aaa=hour2aaa, bbb=hour2bbb, ccc=hour2ccc)], 
 rawtable[,list(nodeID, Hour=24, aaa=hour24aaa, bbb=hour24bbb, ccc=hour24ccc)]))
```

Here is some sample data to play with

```
rawtable<-data.table(nodeID=c(1,2),hour1aaa=c(12.4,32),hour1bbb=c(61.1,65.33),hour1ccc=c(-4.2,54),hour2aaa=c(12.2,1.2),hour2bbb=c(12.2,5.7),hour2ccc=c(5.6,101.9),hour24aaa=c(45.2,8.5),hour24bbb=c(23,7.9),hour24ccc=c(98,32.3))
```

Using my `rbindlist` approach gives the desired result but, as with most things I do with R, there is probably a better way.  By better I mean more memory efficient, faster, and/or uses less lines of code.  Does anyone have a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic `reshape` problem if you get your names in the standard convention it expects, though I'm not sure this really harnesses the efficiency of the `data.table` structure:

```
reshape(
  setNames(rawtable, gsub("(\\D+)(\\d+)(\\D+)", "\\3.\\2", names(rawtable))),
  idvar="nodeID", direction="long", varying=-1
)
```

Result:

```
   nodeID hour  aaa   bbb   ccc
1:      1    1 12.4 61.10  -4.2
2:      2    1 32.0 65.33  54.0
3:      1    2 12.2 12.20   5.6
4:      2    2  1.2  5.70 101.9
5:      1   24 45.2 23.00  98.0
6:      2   24  8.5  7.90  32.3
```

`@Arun`'s answer over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15510828/496803 may also be useful if you can adapt it to your current data.

Comment: +1 I don't think that there would be much of a problem with base R reshape. It always bugs me that `reshape` doesn't go to the trouble to figure out the `varying = list(...)` part, especially when you have to specify `v.names` in those cases.

Comment: @AnandaMahto - a small price to pay I suppose. You could always do `keynames <- c("aaa","bbb","ccc")` and use `lapply(keynames,grep,names(rawtable))` in the `varying` and `keynames` in the `v.names` part. It is a bit of an inconvenience though.

Comment: I have defined a vectorized `grep` for such purposes in my functions: `vGrep <- Vectorize(grep, "pattern", SIMPLIFY = FALSE)`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I changed the 2 data points listed above to `runif(1e6,min=-10,max=10)` for the vars and `1:1e6` for `nodeID` then did system.time on reshape.  It came back with 5.8 vs `rbindlist` approach of 0.19.  This doesn't surprise me as `reshape` isn't very fast in my experience compared to `reshape2` and I'm not aware of an analog in `reshape2` for the `times/timevar` argument in `reshape`.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `merged.stack` from my package "splitstackshape". This function, `stack`s groups of columns and then merges the output together. Because of how the function creates the "time" variable, you can specify whatever you wanted to strip out from the column names. In this case, we want to strip out "hour", "aaa", "bbb", and "ccc" and have just the numbers remaining.

```
library(splitstackshape)
## Make sure you're using at least 1.2.0
packageVersion("splitstackshape")
# [1] ‘1.2.0’
merged.stack(rawtable, id.vars="nodeID", 
             var.stubs=c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"), 
             sep="hour|aaa|bbb|ccc")
#    nodeID .time_1  aaa   bbb   ccc
# 1:      1       1 12.4 61.10  -4.2
# 2:      1       2 12.2 12.20   5.6
# 3:      1      24 45.2 23.00  98.0
# 4:      2       1 32.0 65.33  54.0
# 5:      2       2  1.2  5.70 101.9
# 6:      2      24  8.5  7.90  32.3
```