# Transposing a data frame

Tags: r, plyr, reshape2

I have a question about re-shaping (if that's the right word) a data frame to a transposed version of it. I want to take something like:

```
A   B   C   
1   6   1
1   18  1
1   21  1
3   18  1
3   21  1
4   6   1
4   18  1
4   20  1
4   21  1
```

And turn it into a dataframe like:

```
A   B_1 C_1 B_2 C_2 B_3 C_3 ...
1   6   1   18  1   21  1
3   18  1   21  1   
4   6   1   18  1   20  1   21  1
```

Is there some go-to function in R that I'm unaware of or should I loop over this process?
Thanks!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stack overflow.  The question you are looking for is probably similar to this one:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668870/reshape-wide-format-to-multi-column-long-format/    Some helpful search terms for this question are `[r] [reshape] [reshape2] [plyr]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DF <- read.table(text="A   B   C   
1   6   1
1   18  1
1   21  1
3   18  1
3   21  1
4   6   1
4   18  1
4   20  1
4   21  1",header=TRUE)
```

First create an index variable:

```
library(plyr)
DF <- ddply(DF,.(A),transform,No=seq_along(A))
#   A  B C No
# 1 1  6 1  1
# 2 1 18 1  2
# 3 1 21 1  3
# 4 3 18 1  1
# 5 3 21 1  2
# 6 4  6 1  1
# 7 4 18 1  2
# 8 4 20 1  3
# 9 4 21 1  4
```

Now melt the data.frame and cast to wide format:

```
library(reshape2)
DF <- melt(DF,id.vars=c("A","No"))
res <- dcast(DF,A~No+variable)
#   A 1_B 1_C 2_B 2_C 3_B 3_C 4_B 4_C
# 1 1   6   1  18   1  21   1  NA  NA
# 2 3  18   1  21   1  NA  NA  NA  NA
# 3 4   6   1  18   1  20   1  21   1
```

Order in the formula matters:

```
res <- dcast(DF,A~variable+No)
#   A B_1 B_2 B_3 B_4 C_1 C_2 C_3 C_4
# 1 1   6  18  21  NA   1   1   1  NA
# 2 3  18  21  NA  NA   1   1  NA  NA
# 3 4   6  18  20  21   1   1   1   1
```