# How do I self join a data.table in a manner like dcast

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have a `data.table` in "melted" form where I have a key, and identifier and a value

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
DT = data.table(X = c(1:5, 1:4), Y = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 4)), Z = rnorm(9))
DT2 = data.table(dcast(DT, X~Y))
```

How can I perform that sort of self join inside `data.table`?

```
> DT
   X Y           Z
1: 1 A -0.19790449
2: 2 A  0.17906116
3: 3 A  0.01821837
4: 4 A  0.17309716
5: 5 A  0.05962474
6: 1 B -0.24629468
7: 2 B  0.92285734
8: 3 B  0.66002573
9: 4 B -1.01403880
> DT2
   X           A          B
1: 1 -0.19790449 -0.2462947
2: 2  0.17906116  0.9228573
3: 3  0.01821837  0.6600257
4: 4  0.17309716 -1.0140388
5: 5  0.05962474         NA
```

**Aside (mostly for Arun):**
Here is a solution I already use for melt (was written with help from Matthew D, so he should have this code), that I think replicates melt completely, and is pretty efficient.  Dcast on the other hand (or should that be dtcast?) is much harder!

```
melt.data.table = function(data, id.vars, measure.vars,
                           variable.name = "variable",
                           ..., na.rm = FALSE, value.name = "value") {
  if(missing(id.vars)){
    id.vars = setdiff(names(data), measure.vars)
  }
  if(missing(measure.vars)){
    measure.vars = setdiff(names(data), id.vars)
  }

  dtlist = lapply(measure.vars, function(..colname) {
    data[, c(id.vars, ..colname), with = FALSE][, (variable.name) := ..colname]
  })

  dt = rbindlist(dtlist)
  setnames(dt, measure.vars[1], value.name)
  if(na.rm){
    return(na.omit(dt))
  } else {
    return(dt)
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for sharing your code. As you say, `melt` is easier. I managed to write it in C and it's available in 1.8.11 as of now, if you want to test it out. Currently, I'm trying to get significant speed-ups for `cast` in C. I'll update once I've managed to commit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** faster versions of `melt` and `dcast` are now implemented (in C) in `data.table` versions `>= 1.9.0`. Check [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902087/proper-fastest-way-to-reshape-a-data-table/6913151#6913151) for more info.

Now you can just do:

```
dcast.data.table(DT, X~Y)
```

In case of `dcast` alone, at the moment, it has to be written out completely (as it's not a S3 generic yet in `reshape2`). We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. For `melt,` you can just use `melt(.)` as you'd do normally.

---

The general idea is this:

```
setkey(DT, X, Y)
DT[CJ(1:5, c("A", "B"))][, as.list(Z), by=X]
```

You can name the columns `V1` and `V2` as `A` and `B` using `setnames`.

But this may not be efficient on large data or when the cast formula is complex. Or rather I should say, it could be much more efficient. We're in the process of finding such an implementation to integrate melt and cast on to data.table. Until then, you could get around this as above.

I'll update this post once we've made significant progress with melt/cast.

Comment: Whoa +1 I did not know about `SJ` and `CJ`. Can't wait for a `dcast.data.table` option too!

Comment: Thanks @Arun, I've added the melt code I already have to the end of the question in case it interests you (based on your last sentence).  In a more general case of your answer, I presume I just replace `1:5` with something like `unique(DT[Y %in% c("A","B"), X])` or is there a shorter way?

Comment: Or `DT[CJ(unique(X), unique(Y))][...]` (to avoid `DT$` repetition) and `DT[CJ(unique(X), unique(Y)),...]` to bring as much into one `[...]` as possible for query optimization to have more to chew on (since everything inside `[...]` is delayed evaluation). Btw @Carone, Arun's melt in C should be significantly better than our melt. He's really got into the C side of `data.table` and fixed some segfault bugs too. When you read [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable) it's not always me behind it now.