# Correlation between groups in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table, correlation

Is there a way of elegantly calculating the correlations between values if those values are stored by group in a single column of a data.table (other than converting the data.table to a matrix)?

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)             # reproducibility
dt <- data.table(id=1:4, group=rep(letters[1:2], c(4,4)), value=rnorm(8))
setkey(dt, group)

#    id group      value
# 1:  1     a -0.6264538
# 2:  2     a  0.1836433
# 3:  3     a -0.8356286
# 4:  4     a  1.5952808
# 5:  1     b  0.3295078
# 6:  2     b -0.8204684
# 7:  3     b  0.4874291
# 8:  4     b  0.7383247
```

Something that works, but requires the group names as input:

```
cor(dt["a"]$value, dt["b"]$value)
# [1] 0.1556371
```

I'm looking more for something like:

```
dt[, cor(value, value), by="group"]
```

But that does not give me the correlation(s) I'm after.

Here's the same problem for a matrix with the correct results.

```
set.seed(1)             # reproducibility
m <- matrix(rnorm(8), ncol=2)
dimnames(m) <- list(id=1:4, group=letters[1:2])

#        group
# id           a          b
#   1 -0.6264538  0.3295078
#   2  0.1836433 -0.8204684
#   3 -0.8356286  0.4874291
#   4  1.5952808  0.7383247

cor(m)                  # correlations between groups

#           a         b
# a 1.0000000 0.1556371
# b 0.1556371 1.0000000
```

Any comments or help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no simple way to do this with `data.table`. The first way you've provided:

```
cor(dt["a"]$value, dt["b"]$value)
```

Is probably the simplest.

An alternative is to `reshape` your `data.table` from `"long"` format, to `"wide"` format:

```
> dtw <- reshape(dt, timevar="group", idvar="id", direction="wide")
> dtw
   id    value.a    value.b
1:  1 -0.6264538  0.3295078
2:  2  0.1836433 -0.8204684
3:  3 -0.8356286  0.4874291
4:  4  1.5952808  0.7383247
> cor(dtw[,list(value.a, value.b)])
          value.a   value.b
value.a 1.0000000 0.1556371
value.b 0.1556371 1.0000000
```

---

**Update:** If you're using `data.table` version >= 1.9.0, then you can use `dcast.data.table` instead which'll be much faster. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6913151/559784) for more info.

```
dcast.data.table(dt, id ~ group)
```

Comment: Are you aware of `dcast.data.table`?

Comment: I think I've come across it before, but now that I dig deeper it turns out I'm stuck on an older version of `data.table`

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect the latest version of `data.table`

Comment: Prior to version `1.8.11`, `reshape` didn't work with `data.table`s, because `dcast.data.table` and `melt.data.table` weren't implemented, so you had to cast to a `data.frame` and back.

Comment: @ScottRitchie, not true. I think you're confusing base function from Hadley's package. `reshape` is a base function, that'll work just fine on *all* versions of `data.table`. `reshape` and `reshape2` are also packages with functions melt/cast. `data.table >= 1.9.0` versions implement `melt` and `dcast` methods and imports `reshape2`.

Comment: @Arun thanks for clearing that up. I've verified that `base:reshape` works on 'data.table' without importing the `reshape2 library`. However, for a slightly larger example with 1M rows, `dcast.data.table` is ten times faster than `reshape`, so I'll stick with `dcast` for now.

Comment: @BramVisser, yes, right and right. `dcast.data.table` takes advantage of all data.table internals, + other essentials written in C. Let us know if you come across any issues [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?atid=975&group_id=240&func=browse). Remember you'll have to spell it out completely `dcast.data.table` and not just `dcast` as of now.. It'll be fixed later. If you just use `dcast` it'll use `reshape2's dcast`, which is much slower than `dcast.data.table`.

Answer (score 9):

I've since found an even simple alternative for doing this.  You were actually pretty close with your `dt[, cor(value, value), by="group"]` approach.  What you actually need is to first do a Cartesian join on the dates, and then group by.
I.e.

```
dt[dt, allow.cartesian=T][, cor(value, value), by=list(group, group.1)]
```

This has the advantage that it will join the series together (rather than assume they are the same length).  You can then cast this into matrix form, or leave it as it is to plot as a heatmap in ggplot etc.

**Full Example**

```
setkey(dt, id)
c <- dt[dt, allow.cartesian=T][, list(Cor = cor(value, value.1)), by = list(group, group.1)]
c

   group group.1       Cor
1:     a       a 1.0000000
2:     b       a 0.1556371
3:     a       b 0.1556371
4:     b       b 1.0000000

dcast(c, group~group.1, value.var = "Cor")

  group         a         b
1     a 1.0000000 0.1556371
2     b 0.1556371 1.0000000
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't know a way to get it in matrix form straight away, but I find this solution useful:

```
dt[, {x = value; dt[, cor(x, value), by = group]}, by=group]

   group group        V1
1:     a     a 1.0000000
2:     a     b 0.1556371
3:     b     a 0.1556371
4:     b     b 1.0000000
```

since you started with a molten dataset and you end up with a molten representation of the correlation.

Using this form you can also choose to just calculate certain pairs, in particular it is a waste of time calculating both off diagonals.  For example:

```
 dt[, {x = value; g = group; dt[group <= g, list(cor(x, value)), by = group]}, by=group]
   group group        V1
1:     a     a 1.0000000
2:     b     a 0.1556371
3:     b     b 1.0000000
```

Alternatively, this form works just as well for the cross correlation between two sets (i.e. the block off diagonal)

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)             # reproducibility
dt1 <- data.table(id=1:4, group=rep(letters[1:2], c(4,4)), value=rnorm(8))
dt2 <- data.table(id=1:4, group=rep(letters[3:4], c(4,4)), value=rnorm(8))
setkey(dt1, group)
setkey(dt2, group)

dt1[, {x = value; g = group; dt2[, list(cor(x, value)), by = group]}, by=group]

   group group          V1
1:     a     c -0.39499814
2:     a     d  0.74234458
3:     b     c  0.96088312
4:     b     d  0.08016723
```

Obviously, if you ultimately want these in matrix form, then you can use `dcast` or `dcast.data.table`, however, notice that in the above examples you have two columns with the same name, to fix this it is worth renaming them in the j function.  For the original problem:

```
dcast.data.table(dt[, {x = value; g1=group; dt[, list(g1, g2=group, c =cor(x, value)), by = group]}, by=group], g1~g2, value.var = "c")

   g1         a         b
1:  a 1.0000000 0.1556371
2:  b 0.1556371 1.0000000
```