# Between-Within Correlations

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, correlation

```
DATA = data.frame("GROUP" = sort(rep(1:4, 200)),
                  "TYPE" = rep(1:2, 400),
                  "TIME" = rep(100:101, 400),
                  "SCORE" = sample(1:100,r=T,800))
```

Cheers all,

I have 'DATA' and wish to estimation the CORRELATION VALUES of SCORE at each TIME and SCORE and TYPE combination BETWEEN AND WITHIN GROUP in this way:
[image]

Comment: (1) You're using random data, and the results are not perfectly clear, please start with `set.seed(42)` (or some number) so that we are all using the same random data for reproducibility. (2) What is your expected output? Given this structure, how many rows are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to compute the correlation between groups 1-2, 1-3, 1-4 and so on for each combination of TIME and TYPE. Here's an approach:

```
# create the dataset
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame("group" = sort(rep(1:4, 200)),
                 "type" = rep(1:2, 400),
                 "time" = rep(100:101, 400),
                 "score" = sample(1:100,r=T,800))
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(data.table)

# another dataset to filter combinations 
# (G1G2 is same G2G1, so remove G2G1)
df2 <- combn(4, 2) %>% t %>% 
    as_tibble() %>% 
    rename(group1 = V1, group2 = V2) %>% 
    mutate(value = TRUE)

df %>% 
    
    # add identifiers per group
    group_by(time, type, group) %>% 
    mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    
    # nest data to get separate tibble for each
    # combination of time and type
    nest(data = -c(time, type)) %>% 
    
    # convert each data.frame to data.table
    mutate(dt = map(data, function(dt){
        setDT(dt)
        setkey(dt, id)
        dt
    })) %>% 
    
    # correlation between groups in R
    # refer answer below for more details
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/26357667/15221658
    
    # cartesian join of dts
    mutate(dtj = map(dt, ~.[., allow.cartesian = TRUE])) %>% 
    
    # compute between group correlation
    mutate(cors = map(dtj, ~.[, list(cors = cor(score, i.score)), by = list(group, i.group)])) %>% 
    
    # unnest correlation object
    unnest(cors) %>% 
    
    # formatting for display
    select(type, time, group1 = group, group2 = i.group, correlation = cors) %>% 
    filter(group1 != group2) %>%
    arrange(time, group1, group2) %>% 

    # now use df2 since currently we have G1G2, and G2G1
    # which are both equal so remove G2G1
    left_join(df2, by = c("group1", "group2")) %>% 
    filter(value) %>% 
    select(-value)

# A tibble: 12 x 5
    type  time group1 group2 correlation
   <int> <int>  <int>  <int>       <dbl>
 1     1   100      1      2     0.121  
 2     1   100      1      3     0.0543 
 3     1   100      1      4    -0.0694 
 4     1   100      2      3    -0.104  
 5     1   100      2      4    -0.0479 
 6     1   100      3      4    -0.0365 
 7     2   101      1      2    -0.181  
 8     2   101      1      3    -0.0673 
 9     2   101      1      4     0.00765
10     2   101      2      3     0.0904 
11     2   101      2      4    -0.0126 
12     2   101      3      4    -0.154
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach which creates all unique combinations of `TIME`, `TYPE`, and duplicated `GROUP`s through a *cross join* and then computes the correlation of `SCORE` for the correspondings subsets of `DATA`:

```
library(data.table) # development version 1.14.3 required
setDT(DATA, key = c("GROUP", "TYPE", "TIME"))[
  , CJ(time = TIME, type = TYPE, groupA = GROUP, groupB = GROUP, unique = TRUE)][
    groupA < groupB][
      , corType := paste0("G", groupA, "G", groupB)][][
        , corValue := cor(DATA[.(groupA, type, time), SCORE], 
                          DATA[.(groupB, type, time), SCORE]), 
        by = .I][]
```

> ```
>     time type groupA groupB corType    corValue
>  1:  100    1      1      2    G1G2  0.11523940
>  2:  100    1      1      3    G1G3 -0.05124326
>  3:  100    1      1      4    G1G4 -0.16943203
>  4:  100    1      2      3    G2G3  0.05475435
>  5:  100    1      2      4    G2G4 -0.10769738
>  6:  100    1      3      4    G3G4  0.01464146
>  7:  100    2      1      2    G1G2          NA
>  8:  100    2      1      3    G1G3          NA
>  9:  100    2      1      4    G1G4          NA
> 10:  100    2      2      3    G2G3          NA
> 11:  100    2      2      4    G2G4          NA
> 12:  100    2      3      4    G3G4          NA
> 13:  101    1      1      2    G1G2          NA
> 14:  101    1      1      3    G1G3          NA
> 15:  101    1      1      4    G1G4          NA
> 16:  101    1      2      3    G2G3          NA
> 17:  101    1      2      4    G2G4          NA
> 18:  101    1      3      4    G3G4          NA
> 19:  101    2      1      2    G1G2 -0.04997479
> 20:  101    2      1      3    G1G3 -0.02262932
> 21:  101    2      1      4    G1G4 -0.00331578
> 22:  101    2      2      3    G2G3 -0.01243952
> 23:  101    2      2      4    G2G4  0.16683223
> 24:  101    2      3      4    G3G4 -0.10556083
>     time type groupA groupB corType    corValue
> ```

#### Explanation

1. `DATA` is coerced to class `data.table` while setting a key on columns `GROUP`, `TYPE`, and `TIME`. *Keying* is required for fast subsetting later.
2. The  *cross join* `CJ()` creates all unique combinations of columns `TIME`, `TYPE`, `GROUP`, and  `GROUP` (twice). The columns of the *cross join* have been renamed to avoid name clashes later on.
3. `[groupA < groupB]` ensures that equivalent combinations of `groupA` and `groupB` only appear once, e.g.,  `G2G1` is dropped in favour of `G1G2`. So, this is kind of data.table version of `t(combn(unique(DATA$GROUP), 2))`.
4. A new column `corType` is append *by reference*.
5. Finally, the groupwise correlations are computed by stepping rowwise through the *cross join* table (using `by = .I`) and subsetting `DATA` by `groupA`, `type`, `time` and `groupB`, `type`, `time`, resp., using fast subsetting through `keys`. Please, see the vignette [Keys and fast binary search based subset](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html) for more details.
   Note that `by = .I` is a new feature of `data.table` development version 1.14.3.

Combinations of time, type, and group which do not exist in `DATA` will appear in the result set but are marked by `NA` in  column `corValue`.

#### Data

```
set.seed(42) # required for reproducible data
DATA = data.frame("GROUP" = sort(rep(1:4, 200)),
                  "TYPE" = rep(1:2, 400),
                  "TIME" = rep(100:101, 400),
                  "SCORE" = sample(1:100, r=T, 800))
```