# Fill data.table columns based on values of a column of a different data.table

Tags: r, replace, data.table, multiple-conditions

I have two data tables

```
library(data.table)
dt1 = data.table(ID=c(1,2,3),var=c("var1","var2", "var3"),N=c(12,8,19))
    ID  var  N
1:  1 var1 12
2:  2 var2  8
3:  3 var3 19

dt2 = data.table(ID=c(1,2,3),var1=NA,var2=NA,var3=NA)
   ID var1 var2 var3
1:  1   NA   NA   NA
2:  2   NA   NA   NA
3:  3   NA   NA   NA
```

I would like to fill the var1, var2, var3 columns of dt2 will the values of "N" of dt1, for the corresponding IDs.
So, ideally I would like to have

```
   ID var1 var2 var3
1:  1   12   NA   NA
2:  2   NA    8   NA
3:  3   NA   NA   19
```

I wasn't able to think of something, except looping row by row... but I hope that there is a solution with data.table.

Comment: That's just `dt2 <- dcast(dt1, ID ~ var)` I'll see if I can find a dupe... maybe http://stackoverflow.com/q/6902087/

Comment: @Frank is right. Unless your example is over-simplified?

Comment: Thanx @Frank! It seems you don't need data.table at all...

Comment: Actually, `dcast` is a data.table function (modified for data.tables from the original version in the reshape2 library).